# In PHP, flattening a tree to remove empty elements, keeping children

Tags: php

I have a PHP array representing a tree structure, shown below as `$source` (in reality it could nest deeper or shallower than this).

I want to flatten this structure in order to remove any elements that have `"used" => False`, *but* keep any of their children that have `"used" => True`, promoting them upwards. I always want to keep the very top-level elements ("CreativeWork", "Organization", etc).

```php
$source = array(
    "CreativeWork" => array(
        "used" => False,
        "children" => array(
            "Article" => array(
                "used" => False,
                "children" => array(
                    "ScholarlyArticle" => array(
                        "used" => True,
                        "children" => array()
                    ),
                    "SocialMediaPosting" => array(
                        "used" => True,
                        "children" => array(
                            "BlogPosting" => array(
                                "used" => True,
                                "children" => array()
                            ),
                        )
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            "Book" => array(
                "used" => True,
                "children" => array()
            ),
            "CreativeWorkSeries" => array(
                "used" => False,
                "children" => array(
                    "Periodical" => array(
                        "used" => True,
                        "children" => array()
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    "Organization" => array(
        "used" => False,
        "children" => array(
            "GovernmentOrganization" => array(
                "used" => True,
                "children" => array()
            ),
        )
    ),
    "Person" => array(
        "used" => True,
        "children" => array()
    ),
    "Place" => array(
        "used" => True,
        "children" => array(
            "AdministrativeArea" => array(
                "used" => False,
                "children" => array(
                    "City" => array(
                        "used" => True,
                        "children" => array()
                    ),
                    "Country" => array(
                        "used" => True,
                        "children" => array()
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            "Landform" => array(
                "used" => False,
                "children" => array(
                    "Continent" => array(
                        "used" => True,
                        "children" => array()
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Here's what I want to end up with, with comments indicating which elements have been removed:

```php
$desired = array(
    "CreativeWork" => array(
        "used" => False,
        "children" => array(
            // Removed "Article"
                "ScholarlyArticle" => array(
                    "used" => True,
                    "children" => array()
                ),
                "SocialMediaPosting" => array(
                    "used" => True,
                    "children" => array(
                        "BlogPosting" => array(
                            "used" => True,
                            "children" => array()
                        ),
                    )
                ),
            "Book" => array(
                "used" => True,
                "children" => array()
            ),
            // Removed "CreativeWorkSeries"
                "Periodical" => array(
                    "used" => True,
                    "children" => array()
                )
        )
    ),
    "Organization" => array(
        "used" => False,
        "children" => array(
            "GovernmentOrganization" => array(
                "used" => True,
                "children" => array()
            ),
        )
    ),
    "Person" => array(
        "used" => True,
        "children" => array()
    ),
    "Place" => array(
        "used" => True,
        "children" => array(
            // Removed "AdministrativeArea"
                    "City" => array(
                        "used" => True,
                        "children" => array()
                    ),
                    "Country" => array(
                        "used" => True,
                        "children" => array()
                    ),
            // Removed "Landform"
                "Continent" => array(
                    "used" => True,
                    "children" => array()
                )
        )
    )
);
```

I've tried lots of things. At the moment I've ended up with this, which removes too much, and I can't work out how to make it usefully recursive:

```php
function process_branch(&$branch, $parent_key, $children) {
    foreach($children as $key => $value) {
        if ($value["used"] === False) {
            $branch[$parent_key]["children"] = $value["children"];
        }
    }

    return $branch;
}

foreach($source as $key => $value) {
    process_branch($source, $key, $value["children"]);
}
```

**UPDATE:** My latest attempt is below. It's starting to work but somehow it reinstates elements that are `unset()` in earlier loops:

```php
function process_branch(&$branch, $parent_key, $children) {
    foreach($children as $key => $value) {
        if ($value["used"] === False) {
            process_branch($children, $key, $value["children"]);
            // Add the grandchildren to the parent's children.
            $branch[$parent_key]["children"] = array_merge(
                $children, $value["children"]
            );
            // Both of these unset()s delete elements we need deleted,
            // but neither delete all of them.
            unset($branch[$parent_key]["children"][$key]);
            // unset($children[$key]);
        }
    }
}

foreach($source as $key => $value) {
    process_branch($source, $key, $value["children"]);
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `return` if you don't use the returned value?

Comment: I don’t know. As I said, it doesn’t do what I want.

Comment: Why do you need recursion actually? Are there more levels? At least according to your example there are only 3 levels, always.

Comment: Yes, there could be more or fewer levels: “in reality it could nest deeper or shallower than this”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for an interesting issue)

Here is the code that works (I hope) how you expected:

```
function process_branch(array $array, int $level): array
{
    // update depth to exclude the first level nodes
    ++$level;

    foreach ($array as $key => $subArray) {
        // go to the deepest node on each branch
        $processed_branch = process_branch($subArray['children'] ?? [], $level);

        // if meet needed conditions on way back - update current level (merge children of deleted node with current nodes)
        if ($subArray['used'] === false && $level !== 1) {
            unset($array[$key]);
            $array = array_merge($array, $processed_branch);
            continue;
        }

        // otherwise, just rewrite children for current level (with already excluded sub-levels)
        $array[$key]['children'] = $processed_branch;
    }

    // return updated sub-levels to upper level - this is $processed_branch variable in foreach above
    return $array;
}

var_export(process_branch($source, 0));
```

Comment: This is great, thanks so much! I can see I was heading in roughly the right direction but I don't know if I'd have got there. Is the `: array` at the end of the first line a typo, or something from a more recent version of PHP than the one I'm using? The `??` in line 8 isn't something my (very old) version recognises, but I can work round both of these of course. Thanks again.

Comment: yep, the features you mentioned are from php 7. You can omit them